# Сервис под Android + web сервис (помощь, описание)

Tags: android, архитектура, проектирование, веб-служба, дизайн-api

Разрабатывается сервис в web'e.

Но он должен существовать совместно с приложением на Android'e.

Нашел несколько сайтов по разработке под Android. Почитал, что-то понятно, что-то нет.

Суть вопроса:(всех вопросов по сервису)

1. У web проекта будет API для приложения(IOS,Android) Одинаковое для обоих платформ
2. Приложение должно иметь настройки для синхронизации между сервисом. т.е. если в данный момент нет интернета, по каким либо причинам, то приложение записывает данные у себя, при получении интернета, приложение синхронизируется в сервисом по определенной логике.
3. Как лучше делать синхронизацию данных? Есть данные в БД, в основном это текст небольшой и фотографии, фотки не большие, но все таки, при частом использовании именно сервиса фоток, их соответственно становится много и не сожрет ли приложение всю память на устройстве при синхронизации? Или же отдавать фотки по желанию пользователя, по кнопке допустим "загрузить фотографию" тогда проблема решаема быстро.
4. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с написанием API к сервису? Как они правильно пишутся? Я себе представляю это наверное иначе чем каждый из нас. Может есть идеи?
5. Сервис будет работать изначально на своем одном серваке, как только будет выхлоп, серверов станет больше.
6. Сервис в стадии проектирования по-этому будут выслушаны все мнения по поводу выбора БД, сервера Apache/Nginx, протокола доступа https т.к. будут подключены сервисы от банков. (в данный момент сервис пишется на Yii, сервер Nginx, БД - MySql) Кол-во записей в БД большое выборок из неё так же много, так же смотрим в сторону PostgreSQL - кто о ней скажет что хорошего?

Сервис в основе своей - это некий "калькулятор" для показа пользователю в красивом дизайне тех данных которые он вводил. Кол-во вводимых данных большое, если взять в среднем то 1 пользователь в день может ввести от 1 до 50 разных чисел(назовем их так) т.е. на каждого пользователя до 50 записей в 1 таблицу, которая разбивается еще на несколько со своими связями. Если представить что пользователей несколько тысяч в сутки(это первое время, то кол-во записей то это 100К записей) по мимо своей внутренней статистике и прочих записей в БД. + загрузка фоток и наконец вывод по каким-либо параметрам этих данных, день, неделя, месяц, год, 5 лет и т.д.

Кто в какой сфере сможет подсказать?

ps наверное "Это слишком спорный вопрос" т.к. не сильно является вопросом, но мне это интересно и сервис должен запуститься к лету (альфа точно) :)

Comment: Обновил ответ со ссылкой на почитать про синхронизацию. Довольно подробно расписано то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

1) для базовой части рекомендую выбирать json. На крайний случай - xml. Никаких бинарных протоколов. На будущее всегда можно будет прикрутить по верху ssl и получить и безопасность, и шифрование.

2) а нет никаких проблем с синхронизацией. Более того, на андроидах, начиная с 2.2 есть встроенный механизм для синхронизации (http://habrahabr.ru/post/118450/). Он конечно навязывает свою модель представления данных, но дает определенные гарантии.

3) частично ответил выше. Также не забываем использовать sdcard - я не думаю, что человек легко за сутки наберет гигабайт данных, а на карте обычно есть такой объем памяти. Но это не отменяет контроля памяти.

4) апи писали. Все зависит от задач. Можно делать  на базе REST (гугл по словам "android rest" выдает много интересного). А некоторые берут обычный xmpp протокол. Для него и сервера есть, и клиентские библиотеки и  просто дописывают себе функционал.

5) балансировка нагрузки - классическая задача. Главное, что бы нагрузку на базу правильно разделить (либо настраивать синхронизацию, либо правильное распределение клиентов по серверам)

6) раз в данный момент уже выбрано мускуль, то пусть он и будет. В большинстве случаев переход на другую базу может привести только к проблемам. Сейчас конечно набегут люди, которые будут рекомендовать NoSQL решения, но лучше выбирать то, в чем хорошо разбираетесь.  Поэтому, берите то, то уже есть в данный момент, но не делайте сильную зависимость (то есть не используйте то, что специфично для MySQL) и будет счастье. Если в какой то момент поймете, что мускуль не подходит, перейти будет заметно легче. С другими компонентами та же история. Если хорошо знаете Yii - значит его и используйте.

Answer (score 1):

Из этого всего непонятно главного - в чем вопрос и в чем ваши сложности?

У вас будет апи к сайту. Пишите клиент под андроид, айос или любую ОС.

1. Пишите парсер json, xml или что там сервис будет выдавать
2. Синхронизируете данные на клиенте. Если данные меняются часто, то пишите специальный метод апи и дергайте его, проверяя флаг обновилось нет и меняя данные на клиенте. Если данные меняются нечасто, то обновляйте переодически отправляя запрос с клиента. Можно проверять дату и сравнивать. Способов много - выбирайте наиболее подходящий под ваши требования.
3. Кешируйте все что возможно. Желательно в БД. Инет не всегда бывает на девайсе, а пользователь все равно хочет видеть работающее приложение.
4. Выносите сразу все действий с сетью во внешние потоки(AsyncTask и прочее) - потом скажите спасибо:)
5. Адаптируйте дизайн клиента под популярные разрешения(320х480, 480х800, 1280х800). Этот пункт на будущее, чтобы избежать проблем при проектировании архитектуры и оценки времени.

На почитать про синхронизацию:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829371/sync-data-between-android-app-and-webserver

На почитать про создание приложений:
http://developer.android.com/
http://startandroid.ru/ru/

Comment: 1) писать парсер не нужно, он уже есть, как минимум в андроиде

Comment: классы с пакета json?

Comment: [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)

Comment: Эмм, ок. И разве ответ апи по запросу не нужно разбирать с помощью этих же классов? Не поняяяяятно :) Это и есть парсинг, парсер, любое другое заумное слово:)

Comment: это уже не парсинг будет, а просто разбор данных.

Comment: Это вопрос терминологии. parse - разбор и переводится
http://translate.google.com/#en/ru/parse

Comment: есть вариант синхронизации **клиент->сервер**, а есть **сервер->клиент** и как вариант они оба сразу т.е. именно синхронизация 2х баз либо в одной что-то изменилось либо в другой либо в обеих!

5 пункт не попутал?


>конкретики лучше

дык напиши какой нужно и я опишу.

Comment: странный вопрос. Это зависит от твоих идей по реализации. Вообще в идеале и туда и обратно! Если конечно клиент может модифицировать данные на сервисе, а не только ридонли.

Comment: есть какие-то ссылки на то как реализовывается синхронизация и вообще про создание приложений под Android?

Просто в данный момент пишется именно web сервис, а хочется и параллельно делать приложение