# MongoDB + Yii в чем плюсы такой связки?

Tags: mongodb, yii, mysql

[Разрабатывается сервис](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/187585/api-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android-web-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в нем изначально планируется использовать MySql.

Кол-во транзакций в БД будет большое.

Есть ли смысл использовать для всего этого MongoDB?

Выйдет ли использование этой штуки вызвать проблемы если я с ней еще вообще не сталкивался, а проект в данный момент только разрабатывается структура данных, т.е. на данном этапе можно выбрать компромисс?

Comment: @Shrek, где-то слышал что в `MongoDB` нет транзакций (Хотя я могу ошибаться). Как вы собираетесь обойти это ограничение? Тем более когда речь идет о подсчете финансов.

P.S. Только не подумайте что я вас отговариваю, мне просто самому интересно :))

Comment: @Shrek, если много транзакций, то mongodb вам точно не подходит. Если нужна k-v DB, то, для этих целей, лучше юзайте redis, там они в наличии.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы скорее говорил бы о четком планировании архитектуры, особенно в свете того, что задача должна быть хорошо масштабируема.

То есть задачи:

1. Блинговая часть (которая у вас описана как общение с банками). В идеале отдельный сервер, отдельная БД (лучше MS, можно postgre) и API, с которым работают контент-сервера.
2. Контент сервера. На них лежат данные, они же их принимают. Ну... скорее всего это файловое хранилище(для тех же фото/видео/аудио материалов) + nosql (для текстовых материалов и "списков") + nginx.
3. Сервера "приложений". Обслуживает пользователя, контролирует целостность сессий, распределяет и перенаправляет запросы между контент серверами. Если у вас будет получаться низкое взаимное проникновение пользователей (то есть пользователь работает (получает данные) только с одним "своим" сервером), то данный сервер как таковой и не нужен, его можно интегрировать в П.2.

В идеале, когда веб-морда и внешние сервисы используют одни и те же программные интерфейсы... Но я правда такого готового не встречал, да и нагрузка на сервера местами может быть избыточная. Но всё-таки общие вещи (команда "Отобрать данные на дату", "Сохранить запись" и т.п.) на уровне ядра системы очень желательно реализовать один раз для использования всеми видами клиентов.

Ещё раз по выбору БД.

Там где нужно много разношерстных данных и не нет нужды в сложных отборах - лучше юзать NoSQL - конкретная модель выбирается исходя из отзывов на форумах исходя из того, что и как будет хранится. Я юзал монго (там где становилось жалко файловую систему)... в принципе доволен. Но с другой стороны я много от него и не хотел)

Там где нужна взаимная целостность данных, какие-либо каскадные действия и/или сложные отбры и поиски - вы никуда от SQL пока не уйдете. Конкретные варианты postgre, MSSQL. Если нужен космос - Oracle, но обычно те, кому нужен Оракл, приходят к этому сами, а не по советам на форуме))

Comment: ставлю +1.

Про твой пункт 1. Ты наверное хотел написать биллинговая? Но нет биллинга между банками не будет. Тут скорее всего - наш сервис будет ждать контента от банков по определенному адресу.

Тут ставится вопрос именно в кол-ве записей в секунду и далее как-то записи которые уже не редактируются - допустим месячной давности, переносить в другую таблицу либо на другой сервер, так сказать для архива этих записей, чтобы к основной таблице пользователи меньше делали запросов. Что-то сейчас возникли такие вопросы в голове.

Comment: Мда... Две буквы в одном слове потерять це конечно круто...

Да. Имелася в виду биллинг, не как биржевая система, а как банальный клиент для платежных систем. Ну вы же скорее всего будете взымать с пользователей какую-то плату за расширенные услуги. То есть у вас будет либо снятие сумм ежемесячно, либо баланс с снятие сумм по факту. А это лучше всё-таки делать отдельно.

Comment: Для биллинга и оплаты есть агрегаторы, такие как robokassa.ru вполне хорошо себя зарекомендовала. Вся оплата через них. А расширенный функционал, да, будет покупаться за символическую плату в мес.

Я сейчас уже думаю про несколько БД, которые будут работать параллельно, одна на вставку и обработку большого кол-ва транзакций, вторая БД чисто на общий функционал, который не так требователен к большим вставкам.

Comment: Есть БД пользователей - которая юзается для авторизации, контроля прав доступа ну мож ещё какой чепухи. Она одна (лучше - две в зеркале) - большая и мощная.

Есть БД с данными пользователя. Их может быть много и они могу быть вообще не SQL. Они лежат на понит-серверах (которых может быть дохрена) и обслуживают выдачу контента конечным юзерам.
Их нужно делать так, чтоб вы могли докинуть сервер (когда на имеющихся закончится проц, канал, место на винте) и все бы было хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

т.к. в коммент не влезает отвечаю ответом на ответ [[[[@heavy_metal_fan](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan)](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan)](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan)](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan)

По порядку.

- Document Object ( известные также как No-SQL ) базы данных, предназначены для хранения очень больших данных - даже в сотни т**Е**рабайт/петабайт итп - они изначально разрабатывались для этих целей и соответсвенно они с самого начала уже оптимизированы под это.

Про кол-во данных - их много, но они маленькие по сути, но их реально много. На одного пользователя пока примерно от 10-300Кб на запись. Дальше посчитать можно по памяти сколько и что будет занимать. Это только примерные расчеты, пока даже ничего тестить и данных для тестов нет.

- Вы должны ответить себе так: Планирую ли я иметь "ну очень огромную" базу данных и сотни\или тысячи серверов для репликации с оптимизирированными CRUD операциями.

Откуда такие данные про сотни и тысячи серверов? Сотней не будет, хотя не буду никуда заглядывать и загадывать. Но БД будет большая.

- если каждый месяц вы планируете увеличивать БД на несколько ПЕТАБАЙТ = Монго, если нет - MySQL.

Как-то привязано  и натянуто. Ну не будет 1 раз в месяц столько, а будет раз в 4ре месяца, что теперь все монго не катит? Только Мускул? Нет примеров в ответе, не ясно из-за чего такие высказывания.

- Краткий ответ: Если проект "кастомный" - то лучше использовать правильные (признанные сообществом) фрэймворки, такие как, Zend 2, Symfony 2, вместо Yii. (Исходя из личного впечатления, крайне НЕ РЕКОМЕДНУЮ.)

И что? Мне из всех фреймов именно Yii нравится. И никто не может переубедить меня в этом. В чем было личное впечатление того что фрейм - лажа?

- Yii фрэймворк неправильно описывает архитектуру MVC в документации

Ткни пальцем туда!

Из всего что прочитал, честно не увидел ничего хорошего, кроме 2-3х фраз относящихся к теме вопроса.
Про масштабируемость системы загадывать сразу не буду, но она должна быть.

ps пишите еще почитает подискутируем

//upd 2

По-моему все что тут написано товарищем [[[[@heavy_metal_fan](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan)](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan)](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan)](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan) про Yii просто бред.

Слова человека, который просто открыл первый попавшийся файл, мельком его поглядел, сделал выводы и теперь плюется так ни разу не установив его и не использовал.

+ у автора сложно с русским языком, я вот пока читал язык сломал на некоторых словах.

> Зачем тыкать пальцем, когда я
> конкретно говорю адрес: документация
> Yii->MVC - пользователю этого
> фрэймворка !?

Действительно зачем тыкать, если не знаешь куда. В том-то и суть, что никаких доказательств я просто не вижу! Вода водой.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ для [@heavy_metal_fan](/users/11238/heavy_metal_fan)

> CApplication is the base class for all application classes.
> Что само по себе АНТИ-ПАТТЕРН.
> Абстрактный базовый класс для всех
> потомков "приложения".
> Суть в том, что, этот "базовый класс"
> отвечает абсолютно за все и за
> безопасноть, и за роутер и за базу
> данных и за языки и за обработку
> ошибок и за кодировку.. итд.

Ну что за бред?
Контролеры наследуются от СController, которые наследуются от CComponent.
Роутер тоже не наследует CApplication и уж CException тоже явно не наследуется от CApplication!
Зачем вообще писать такой грозный пост совсем не разобравшись с сабжем?
Возьми PhpStorm и посмотри диаграммы классов, тогда ты поймешь, что Yii состоит из компонентов и все компоненты наследуются от CComponent (не удивительно, правда?) этот класс реализует "магические" методы, работу с событиями и поведением, эти методы нужны любому компоненту, похожая штука есть и в Ruby и в Rails, могу привести примеры, если так хочется.

Comment: Да тут с ним все понятно, решил написать бред и свалить. все просто.

Comment: @Shrek Твоя тупость просто не может не раздражать. Спроси тебя что такое, LoD, SOLID, PSR-0, Mocking, ты хотя бы один паттерн знаешь (или значения этого слова)? Конечно же нет и это так очевидно. Потому что если бы ты хотя бы малую часть знал из всего вышеуказанного, ты бы понял о чем речь. Я тебе про Ивана, ты про Балвана.

Моя ошибка в том, что я вообще что-то начал обьяснять. Пост я сейчас удалю.